# How do I get changed items by angular $watch or $watchCollection

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to track the changes of items in an array. see sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cairabbit/ygy96u4j/1/):

```
angular.module('watchApp', []).controller('watchCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.items = [
    {value: 1},
    {value: 2},
    {value: 3}
];

$scope.newItems = [];
$scope.deleteItems = [];
$scope.modifiedItems = [];
$scope.$watchCollection('items', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal);
    console.log(oldVal);
    for(var i=0; i<newVal.length; i++) {
        if (oldVal.indexOf(newVal[i])<0) {
            $scope.newItems.push(newVal[i]);
        }
    }
    for(var i=0; i<oldVal.length; i++) {
        if (newVal.indexOf(oldVal[i])<0) {
            $scope.deleteItems.push(oldVal[i]);
        }
    }
});
$scope.addOne = function () {
    $scope.items.push({value:$scope.items.length+1});
};
$scope.remove = function (it) {
    $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(it), 1);
};
```

});

I can now track the new added and removed items with latest version (1.5.0) of angular. However, I don't know how to get the modified items in the array. Simply use `$watch('items', function..., true)` doesn't work. that will make all items as new items, and all old items as deleted, including unchanged items.

Comment: `$watch` and `$watchCollection` just tell you that the array content has changed, you are responsible for finding the difference between the old and new version of the array yourself.

Comment: yes, that's what I thought too. It seems that in angular, if you want to track what has been changed rather than just fire an notify event, that would be quite difficult and inefficient.

Comment: No, it would be inefficient if Angular would always track what has been changed since this is more complex to compute and is often times not even needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `$watchCollection` function, you need to calculate the difference between the two versions of your array. I recommend using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#difference) for this. For checking if an item was removed or added, I compare the lengths of `newValue` and `oldValue`.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('items', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue.length > oldValue.length) {   
        console.log(_.difference(newValue, oldValue));
    } else {   
        console.log(_.difference(oldValue, newValue));
    } 
});
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9ksr1ue/1/) for a simple demo.

If you do not want to use *lodash* you will need to compare the two arrays by hand.

Comment: This just an example, I know other libraries can check the difference between objects and array. I just want to know what is the proper way in anguarjs. In other words, can I use watch or watchCollection to detect what exactly changed rather than just fire a change event. Sometimes we need to handle special cases only when the specified item in an array change or the specified property of an item changed. In knockoutjs, you can subscribe an event to a specified property or other observable object. How does it do in angularjs.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to your question, `$watch` and `$watchCollection` don't tell you the specific items that changed. They give you the old and new version so you can compare yourself (it would be bad for performance if Angular would always do this even though you don't need it). The way I showed is the proper way in Angular.